# Is it possible to use Visual Studio to write intel assembly?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, assembly, masm

As the title states really, is it possible to write assembly code in visual studio?

Im looking for an easy to use IDE for writing intel assembly language. I looked at a few IDEs a few months ago and unless they required lots of configuration settings (I copy and pasted examples into the IDE) they wouldnt work......

There must be a simple IDE very similar to VS where you can write your assembly, pick CPU and then execute?

Answer (score 3):

The inline assembler in Visual Studio isn't reliable, but you can use Visual Studio in conjunction with [MASM (the Microsoft Macro Assembler)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) to write straight assembly programs.

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/c53fd4fd-e239-464a-b512-2b2fc8745c88
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afzk3475.aspx
- http://www.masm32.com/index.htm
- http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/8072
- http://www.infernodevelopment.com/introduction-masm32

Writing the "glue" code that opens a window, sets up output, *etc* in assembly is rather painful, so you may find it more comfortable to write most of your program in C++, and just a couple of files in assembly. That way you can start by writing simple test functions in straight assembly, and call them from your C++ framework.

Comment: @Nocturn : It isn't supported on x64. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93.aspx )

Also, I've noticed some code generation bugs in cases where I inline assemble into the middle of a C++ function - like if I have a big function, and in the middle of it I use an __asm block that tries to load the C++ variables onto registers, occasionally the wrong variable will be loaded, or the registers will be clobbered.

It doesn't happen often; I think it's simply that Microsoft isn't supporting the inline assembler much any more, and rare bugs are starting to creep in.

Comment: @Nocturn What *still* works for me (in x86 anyway), is writing __declspec(naked) functions that are all assembly, and then calling them from C. I haven't hit any compiler bugs doing that yet. I do still sometimes use ordinary inline assembly too, but I have to go and check the generated code (eg with /FACS) afterwards to make sure it came out right.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out [Setting Up Visual Studio 10 for MASM32 Programming](http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/setting-up-visual-studio-10-for-masm32-programming/)